# If $\sigma^2=1$ then $G$ must be abelian

Tags: group-theory

Exercise from my lecturer. I haven't found any idea.

Let $G$ be a finite group. Suppose that $\sigma\in \text{Aut}(G)$. If $\sigma^2=1$ and $\sigma(x)\ne x$ for $1\ne x\in G$, show that $G$ must be abelian.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hints:** Let $\mu : x \mapsto x^{-1}\sigma(x)$.

- Show that $\mu : G \to G$ is a bijection.
- Notice that $\sigma \circ \mu(x)= \mu(x)^{-1}$ for all $x \in G$.
- Deduce that $\sigma(x)=x^{-1}$ for all $x \in G$.
- Conclude.

Comment: I think the hardest part in your hint is to show $\mu$ is a bijection. Would you show the proof for the first hint?

Comment: Because $G$ is finite, it is sufficient to prove that $\mu$ is injective.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** It suffices to show that for any $\alpha,\beta \in G$:

> $$(\alpha\beta)^2=\alpha^2\beta^2$$

Can you see why?

---

**EDIT:** As HSN pointed out, knowing the above allows us to conclude that:
$$
\beta\alpha=(\alpha^{-1}\alpha)\beta\alpha(\beta\beta^{-1})
=\alpha^{-1}(\alpha\beta\alpha\beta)\beta^{-1}
=\alpha^{-1}(\alpha\beta)^2\beta^{-1}
=\alpha^{-1}(\alpha^2\beta^2)\beta^{-1}
=\alpha\beta
$$

Comment: no, i can't see why.

Comment: $(\alpha\beta)^2=\alpha\beta\alpha\beta$. If this equals $\alpha^2\beta^2$, you can cancel out an $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and get commutativity.

Comment: no,i can't see where the equation $(\alpha\beta)^2=\alpha^2\beta^2$ comes from...