# Finite Abelian Groups and Automorphisms of Groups

Tags: finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group, $T \in \text{Aut}(G)$ such that $T(x)=x$ implies $x = e$.

Show that for all $g \in G$ there exists $x \in G$ with $g = x^{-1}T (x)$.

Thanks to all.

Comment: Why does the title mention abelian groups?

Comment: The title of my book is "finite abelian groups and automorphisms of groups"

Answer (score 2):

Hint: show $x\mapsto x^{-1}T(x)$ is an endomorphism; check its kernel to find it's an automorphism.

Comment: (Note that the condition of $G$ being abelian is necessary for the map to be a morphism of groups, and the condition of $G$ being finite is necessary for injectivity to imply bijectivity.)

Comment: This seems to use that $G$ is abelian.  Are you of the opinion that the OP meant to include that as a hypothesis?  (I am, I think.)

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Based on the title and tag choice: of course.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Show that $x \mapsto x^{-1}T(x)$ is injective and conclude by cardinality.

In fact, if such $T$ exists then $G$ is necessarly abelian, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430039/if-sigma2-1-then-g-must-be-abelian/).